# Import Cordova CDVPlugin.h in iOS framework's umbrella header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cordova

Firstly I will explain the context of my situation:
I created an `Objective-C iOS framework` that has embedded the Cordova framework project (`CordovaLib`) trying to emulate what a cordova app does, but using an `iOS framework` instead of an application. Also I have an iOS native application that uses my framework. (I've attached an image at the bottom to understand better the structure).

Since I don't have a Cordova app, I cannot use the `cordova plugin add` command to install plugins, so when I want to use any new plugin I copy the files manually and change some other files depending on the plugin in order to install the plugin manually. This has been working alright for all plugins that I have installed, until I tried to do the same process with the iosrtc plugin (https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc). This plugin has a bridging header to import objective-c files into swift files, so when this plugin is used in an “normal” application the `Objective-C Bridging Header` build setting has to be used specifying the bridging header file path.

This works alright in a “normal” application, problem is that I'm not installing this in an application, I'm “installing” it in an iOS framework that tries to work as a cordova application. So when a tried to specify the bridging header path in the `Objective-C Bridging Header` build setting, I got this error:

> “using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported”.

Then in other words I cannot use a bridging header in my framework.

**First question:** How could I handle this imports that are in the bridging header file, without using a bridging header?

Researching I found that I could move the imports from the bridging header to my framework's umbrella header but changing the visibility of the files that I want to import, to public. This worked for all imported files but this: `Cordova/CDVPlugin.h`

This file's visibility is already public, the problem is that it is in the CordovaLib project so I'm getting this error:

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyModule'.

**Second question:** How could I import this file in my umbrella header?

[See the directories structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOy1w.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution?